# Filter List of Attributes with .localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare

Tags: core-data, filter, swiftui, searchbar

I'm trying to implement a search bar to filter a list containing attributes of an entity but an error occurs: "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'name'"

Do you have any suggestions to give me to solve, what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

```
Section(header: Text("Users")) {                    
   ForEach(users.filter { self.serchedText == "" ? true : $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(self.serchedText) }, id: \.self) { user in
          HStack {
                Text("\(user.name)")
                Text(" age: \(user.age)")
                Text("height: \(user.height)")
                 }
   }.padding()
}
```